# how to access controls in ListView EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a problem with EditItemTemplate.
I'm using Telerik RadUpload in asp listView.
In validating Event of radUpload, I want to check some Requirements so I need to findControl two control: radUpload and Label

For this I am using ItemDataBound Event of listView 
but the problem is here, first ItemDataBound event execute and after that RadUpload Validating event will execute, therefor the radUpload Control and Label control remain empty

I handle this in a way by using static control, but i think that is not good idea.

Do you have a solution for that?

Another problem is with label. However I using static label and in trace shows the label have text but in output label not seen

```
<asp:ListView ID="LvAdminRing" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemPlaceHolder" GroupPlaceholderID="GroupPlaceHolder"
             OnItemEditing="LvAdminRing_ItemEditing" OnItemDataBound="onItemDataBound" OnItemUpdating="LvAdminRing_ItemUpdating">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="GroupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <div>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ItemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <div class="RadRingTileDIV col-lg-12" runat="server">
                    <div class="row RadRingItemsDIV">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" CssClass="CustDispBlock CustItemFonts" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("XPrice")%>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCode" CssClass="CustDispBlock CustItemFonts" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("XCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row RadRingItemsDIV ">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgRingEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/Image/Admin/CommandsPic/Edit.gif" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgRingDel" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Image/Admin/CommandsPic/Delete.gif" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>

                <div class="RadRingTileDIV col-lg-12" runat="server">
                    <div class="RadRingItemsDIV row">
                        <img src="ksdla" class="AdminImg CustDispBlock" />
                        <telerik:RadUpload ID="RupAdminRingPic" runat="server" AllowedFileExtensions=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.jpe" AllowedMimeTypes="image/png,image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg"
                            MaxFileInputsCount="1" MaxFileSize="52000" OverwriteExistingFiles="False" TargetFolder="~/Image/Products/Ring"
                            OnValidatingFile="RupAdminRingPic_ValidatingFile" ToolTip="انتخاب عکس جدید با پسوند های png،jpg،jpeg و jpe" ControlObjectsVisibility="CheckBoxes">
                        </telerik:RadUpload>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row RadRingItemsDIV">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test" CommandName="Update" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row RadRingItemsDIV">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="LblError" CssClass="CustDispBlock CustZ-Index" Visible="false"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </EditItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

```
public static Label lblError;

    public static RadUpload RuEditPic;
    public static Label lblError;

    protected void RupAdminRingPic_ValidatingFile(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.ValidateFileEventArgs e)
    {
        //Label test = (Label)LvItems.FindControl("LblError");
        string[] AllowedFileExt = RuEditPic.AllowedFileExtensions;
        foreach ( string AllowedExt in AllowedFileExt )
        {
            if (e.UploadedFile.ContentLength > RuEditPic.MaxFileSize)
            {
                lblError.Text = "some error";
                lblError.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = (e.Item as ListViewDataItem).DataItemIndex;

        if (LvAdminRing.EditIndex == (e.Item as ListViewDataItem).DataItemIndex)
        {
            LvItems = LvAdminRing.Items as ListViewDataItem;
            lblError = (e.Item.FindControl("LblError") as Label);
            //errNoti = (e.Item.FindControl("LblError") as Label);
            RuEditPic = (e.Item.FindControl("RupAdminRingPic") as RadUpload);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {

        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        if (dataItem.DisplayIndex == ListView1.EditIndex)
        {
        TextBox tb = e.Item.FindControl("tbFK_MenuID") as TextBox;
        }
    }
}
```